# How to populate checkbox in Zend custom composite element?

Tags: zend-framework, checkbox, element, composite, populate

In Zend I have a custom composite element which consists of two text fields and a checkbox.

This is the view helper:

```
<?php
class My_View_Helper_WorkplaceFactor extends Zend_View_Helper_FormElement{

protected $html = '';

public function workplaceFactor($name, $value = null, $attribs = null){
    $this->html = '';
    $factor = $applies = $note = '';
    if($value){
        $factor = $value['factor'];
        $applies = $value['applies'];
        $note = $value['note'];
    }

    $helperText = new Zend_View_Helper_FormText();
    $helperText->setView($this->view);
    $helperCheckbox = new Zend_View_Helper_FormCheckbox();
    $helperCheckbox->setView($this->view);

    $checked = 0;
    if($applies == "1"){
        $checked = 1;
    }

    $this->html .= '<td><label for="' . $name . '[factor]">Faktor</label></td><td>' . $helperText->formText($name . '[factor]', $factor) . '</td>';
    $this->html .= '<td><label for="' . $name . '[applies]">Platí</label></td><td>' . $helperCheckbox->formCheckbox($name . '[applies]', $applies, array('checked' => $checked)) . '</td>';
    $this->html .= '<td><label for="' . $name . '[note]">Poznámka</label></td><td>' . $helperText->formText($name . '[note]', $note) . '</td>';

    return $this->html;
}
```

}

My problem is populating the checkbox when the form is not valid and reloads itself. When I check the checkbox and reload, it's okay and it populates. When I uncheck the checked one, it's also okay and displays correctly upon reload. But when I want to check the checkbox AFTER the page has been reloaded, the checked value isn't even in the post request so it doesn't work.

The element's markup is as follows:

```
<tr id="factor1">
<td><label for="factor1[factor]">Faktor</label></td><td><input type="text" name="factor1[factor]" id="factor1-factor" value="Prach" /></td>
<td><label for="factor1[applies]">Platí</label></td><td><input type="hidden" name="factor1[applies]" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" name="factor1[applies]" id="factor1-applies" value="0" /></td>
<td><label for="factor1[note]">Poznámka</label></td><td><input type="text" name="factor1[note]" id="factor1-note" value="" /></td></tr>
```

I have wandered around stackoverflow and I think the problem is that the checkbox name has the [] in it but if I don't put them there, the 'applies' checkbox value doesn't belong to the 'factor' values array and so it doesn't populate at all. Do you have any idea how to find a way of this magic circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so with a help of my friend and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9225535/1322246 I modified the helper this way:

```
...
    $checked = isset($value['applies']) && $value['applies'];

    $this->html .= '<td><label for="' . $name . '[factor]">Faktor</label></td><td>' . $helperText->formText($name . '[factor]', $factor) . '</td>';
    $this->html .= '<td><label for="' . $name . '[applies]">Platí</label></td><td>' . $helperCheckbox->formCheckbox($name . '[applies]', $applies, array('value' => 1, 'checked' => $checked), array(1, null)) . '</td>';
    $this->html .= '<td><label for="' . $name . '[note]">Poznámka</label></td><td>' . $helperText->formText($name . '[note]', $note) . '</td>';

...
```

}

So in other words I had to set the checkedValue and uncheckedValue for the zend checkbox view helper. Now it works.